# Modem Connector stuck inside adapter

Tags: connection, modem, adapter

I bought this power adapter and it comes with some ports.

I followed the instructions on the sheet but it wouldn't work.

So I tried to unplug it, but the connector inside is too deep.

[image: The deepness inside the connector]

Any help to get it out?

Comment: it's a locking connector, like ethernet but smaller. Top or bottom it has a key to release it [picture is too fuzzy to see which]. Fingernail or small screwdriver, press towards the plug to release the spring

Comment: The top has a key

Comment: So engage it, and remove the connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to either take a very small slotted screwdriver and try to poke it on the sides to help it get out or just try to pull it away as is.

The second way is obviously the most risky and one I wouldn't suggest, but in the past it happened quite often to me (unintentionally, that is), nothing was stuck, but the plastic on those cables is pretty easy to break, more so than that on the modems, routers etc...

I would definitely try with a small screwdriver first.

EDIT: now that I think about it tweezers may be even better than a screwdriver, if you happen to have any!